# Is there a tool for node.js that will give me the list of all the objects in the heap denoted by their class name string?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to debug a high memory usage situation in a node.js service thats touching almost 1.5 GB of Resident memory usage according to top. I need to see which objects are the culprits of the usage.

Comment: I think that the only way you'll be able to do this is by debugging V8, not Node itself

Comment: the other question is, is the top Resident memory usage a good indication of the heap size or not?

Comment: does it spike or creep up overtime.

Answer (score 2):

You can try :

1. [nodetime](https://npmjs.org/package/nodetime): See the [docs](http://docs.nodetime.com/#memory-profiling) on how to profile memory. A [blog](http://blog.nodetime.com/2012/07/detecting-memory-leaks-in-nodejs-apps.html) on how to detect memory leaks. It can show the largest memory blocks in the heap.
2. [node-inspector](https://npmjs.org/package/node-inspector) with [v8-profiler](https://npmjs.org/package/v8-profiler): Heap snapshots may be taken and viewed from the profiles panel.

To use the inbuilt V8 profiler from command line you can :

1. To build from source:
   `node-gyp configure build install`
2. Or, if you have npm installed:
   `npm install profiler` (See [profiler](https://npmjs.org/package/profiler) for more details)

You can see other profilers mentioned [here](https://nodejsmodules.org/tags/profiler) and [here](https://nodejsmodules.org/tags/profiler).