# Node.js async parallel - what consequences are?

Tags: node.js, sockets, ubuntu, asynchronous

There is code,

```
async.series(tasks, function (err) {
    return callback ({message: 'tasks execution error', error: err});
});
```

where, `tasks` is array of functions, each of it peforms HTTP request (using `request` module) and calling MongoDB API to store the data (to MongoHQ instance).

With my current input, (~200 task to execute), it takes

```
  [normal mode] collection cycle: 1356.843 sec. (22.61405 mins.)
```

But simply trying change from `series` to `parallel`, it gives magnificent benefit. The almost same amount of tasks run in `~30 secs` instead of `~23 mins`.

But, knowing that nothing is for free, I'm trying to understand what the consequences of that change? Can I tell that number of open sockets will be much higher, more memory consumption, more hit to DB servers?

Machine that I run the code is only 1GB of RAM Ubuntu, so I so that app hangs there one time, can it be caused by lacking of resources?

Comment: You should probably tweak and use `async.parallelLimit(array, limit, cb)` for better performance. Find a limit of parallel executions that does not overflow the execution, and it will be faster than async.parallel :P As a bonus, it will not hang anymore :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your intuition is correct that the parallelism doesn't come for free, but you certainly may be able to pay for it.

Using a load testing module (or collection of modules) like [nodeload](https://npmjs.org/package/nodeload), you can quantify how this parallel operation is affecting your server to determine if it is acceptable.

[Async.parallelLimit](https://github.com/caolan/async#parallellimittasks-limit-callback) can be a good way of limiting server load if you need to, but first it is important to *discover if limiting is necessary*. Testing explicitly is the best way to discover the limits of your system (eachLimit has a different signature, but could be used as well).

Beyond this, common pitfalls using async.parallel include wanting more complicated control flow than that function offers (which, from your description doesn't seem to apply) and using parallel on too large of a collection naively (which, say, may cause you to bump into your system's file descriptor limit if you are writing many files). With your ~200 request and save operations on 1GB RAM, I would imagine you would be fine as long as you aren't doing much massaging in the event handlers, but if you are experiencing server hangs, parallelLimit could be a good way out.

Again, testing is the best way to figure these things out.

Comment: I exactly experience server hang after 24-30 hours working of application (even with serial execution), only one workaround now is to restart app. I'm woundering is that because of out of memory or something (no errors, but http request just hangs)..

Comment: That sounds like a memory leak more than an overloaded server to me. How often are you running the 200 task cycle per 24-30 hour period?

Comment: Very often, up to 100 times.. I also suspect memory leak, but it just hard to tackle it.

Comment: I'd expect you are leaking objects or function objects then. If you'd care to post some code I can take a look.

Comment: I afraid it could be a bit difficult, since the code base is not so small.. https://github.com/likeastore/collector/tree/master/source - but if you notice some obvious error, would be great.

Comment: This is somewhat guesswork, not actually having implemented the application, but it looks to me like scheduler.js might have some of its tasks leak. In collector.js, how are you requiring the ./engine/connectors folder and using it without an error?

Comment: Also note that the `set.Timeout` in scheduler.js preserves the `run` function's scope until the timeout fires. This includes all the created tasks.

Comment: thanks a lot.. looks like `setTimeout` really caused some leaking, I've refactored the code like https://github.com/likeastore/collector/blob/memory-leak/source/engine/scheduler.js if you have few minutes, will be happy for suggestions;

Comment: Seems improved, memory-wise. Is it performing well?

Comment: It is! I used `node-memwatch`, even I resieve few `leaks` detection it's definitely better than before. thanks for your help!

Comment: Great to hear! Good luck to you and glad to be of assistance.

Answer (score 3):

I would point out that `async.parallel` executes multiple functions **concurrently** not (completely) **parallely**. It is more like virtual parallelism.

Executing concurrently is like running different programs on a single CPU core, via multitasking/scheduling. True parallel execution would be running different program on each core of multi-core CPU. This is important as node.js has **single-threaded** architecture.

The best thing about node is that you don't have to worry about I/O. It handles I/O very efficiently.

In your case you are storing data to MongoDB, is mostly I/O. So running them parallely will use up your network bandwidth and if reading/writing from disk then disk bandwidth too. Your server will not hang because of CPU overload.

---

The consequence of this would be that if you overburden your server, your requests may fail. You may get `EMFILE` error (Too many open files). Each socket counts as a file. Usually connections are pooled, meaning to establish connection a socket is picked from the pool and when finished return to the pool. You can increase the file descriptor with `ulimit -n xxxx`.

You may also get socket errors when overburdened like `ECONNRESET`(Error: socket hang up), `ECONNREFUSED` or `ETIMEDOUT`. So handle them with properly. Also check the maximum number of simultaneous connections for mongoDB server too.

---

Finally the server can hangup because of garbage collection. Garbage collection kicks in after your memory increases to a certain point, then runs periodically after some time. The max heap memory V8 can have is around 1.5 GB, so expect GC to run frequently if its memory is high. Node will crash with `process out of memory` if asking for more, than that limit. So fix the memory leaks in your program. You can look at these [tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16271946/is-there-a-tool-for-node-js-that-will-give-me-the-list-of-all-the-objects-in-the/16283608).

Answer (score 0):

The main downside you'll see here is a spike in database server load.  That may or may not be okay depending on your setup.

If your database server is a shared resource then you will probably want to limit the parallel requests by using `async.eachLimit` instead.

Answer (score 0):

you'll realize the difference if multiple users connect:

in this case the processor can handle multiple operations

asynch tries to run several operations of multiple users relative equal

```
T = task
U = user
(T1.U1 = task 1 of user 1)

T1.U1 => T1.U2 => T2.U1 => T8.U3 => T2.U2 => etc
```

this is the oposite of atomicy (so maybe watch for atomicy on special db operations - but thats another topic)

so maybe it is faster to use:

```
T2.U1 before T1.U1
```

- this is no problem until

```
T2.U1 is based on T1.U1
```

- this is preventable by using callbacks/ or therefore are callbacks

...hope this is what you wanted to know... its a bit late here